# Compare treatment effects between groups - 2x2x2 ANOVA does not work?

Tags: anova, interaction

I'm working on a psychology thesis where I have fours groups (2 dichotomous variables). 
I want to prove that the difference between treatment and control is larger in one group compared to the other three groups (the outcome variable in continuous). A 2x2x2 (var1 x var2 x treatment/control) ANOVA will not work (in my understanding) since it will only show that one/more of the eight groups differ compared to the other groups. Or is it actually the case that the interaction term(s) will capture the difference that I want to prove exists? Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

First, you should cross the grouping variables to make one 4-level group variable. Then run a two-way 4x2 ANOVA with treatment. If the interaction is significant, that means the treatment effect depends on group. To figure out whether the specific differences that you are interested in testing exist, you need to use contrasts.

To answer the question of the whether the treatment effect is larger in one group vs. all the other groups combined, you will create contrasts that allow you to perform a 1-df test comparing the difference between treatment and control in the focal group and the average of the differences between treatment and control in the other groups. To answer the question of whether the treatment effect is larger in the focal group than in each of the other groups, you will need to perform three 1-df tests that compare the difference between treatment and control in the focal group to the difference between the treatment and control in each other group.

Depending on the software you're using, it might be more straightforward to use the following procedure to perform these tests. First, cross the treatment and group variables to create an 8-level condition variable. You can then run a oneway ANOVA with this variable. From within the ANOVA, you can specify the specific contrasts easily. If levels of your new variable are

```
A1|B1|T A1|B2|T A2|B1|T A2|B2|T A1|B1|C A1|B2|C A2|B1|C A2|B2|C
```

where `A` and `B` are the two grouping variables and `1` and `2` are the levels of each, and `T` is treatment and `C` is control, you can specify the contrast matrix as follows to answer the question of whether the treatment effect in the focal group (we'll say it's `A1|B1`) differs from that in the other groups combined:

```
 [1, -1/3, -1/3, -1/3, -1, 1/3, 1/3, 1/3]
```

To specify the contrast matrix to test whether the treatment effect in the focal group differs from that in each other group, you would use the following:

```
 [1, -1, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0]
```

This contrasts tests whether the treatment effect differs between `A1|B1` and `A1|B2`. You can adjust the contrasts to run the other two tests.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Is there any litterature that describes this that I can cite? Any suggestions how I do this in either Stata or R? Also, I've seen that log odds-ratios sometimes are used. What is the difference (pros/cons) between this contrast and log-OR (or other common approaches). Just in case my professor asks why I choosed this method and what altertnatives there are. Thanks again for the quick answer!!

Comment: These are fundamental ANOVA techniques, so you could find them in a textbook aimed at first-year graduate students in psychology. I would recommend looking up a textbook that focuses on ANOVA in R or Stata. Log-ORs are for binary *outcomes* and the choice of whether to use them is unrelated to everything I've said here. If you have binary outcomes you should not be using ANOVA.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using anovacontrast in Stata (needs to be installed). Here is the code:

```
capture drop x
egen x = group(x1 x2 x3), label

table x, contents(mean y)

anova y x
anovacontrast x, values(-1 1   3 -3  -1  1  -1  1)
anovacontrast x, values( 0 0   1 -1  -1  1   0  0)
anovacontrast x, values(-1 1   1 -1   0  0   0  0)
anovacontrast x, values( 0 0   1 -1   0  0   1 -1)
```

This worked for me.